# How to write a URL function?

Tags: java, string, function, substring, indexof

i'm new to Java, so i have a little problem here...

i need to write a function that extracts the server name from the URL
It means the following:
For a row of the form http://SomeServerName/abcd/dfdf.htm?dfdf=dfdf
i need to isolate "SomeServerName"

- The string may not necessarily start with http, but also with https
  or something else. But :// there is always
- Consider the case when there is no more slash after :// (for example http://SomeServerName)
- I need to use only indexOf and substring

```
// This is what i got so far

public static String getURL(String string) {
    int startIndex = string.indexOf('/') + 2;

    int endIndex = string.indexOf("/", startIndex);

    return string.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "https://SomeServerName/abcd/dfdf.htm?dfdf=dfdf";

        System.out.println(getURL(string));
    }
```

Comment: "I need to use only indexOf and substring" why? Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: This should already work for the URL that you provided. In case there is no more slash after the host name, `endIndex` will be `-1`. Check for that case and adjust the parameters for `substring` accordingly.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Java has classes for parsing URLs and extracting the components already. Or is this a homework task?

Comment: exactly, this is my homework task

Comment: @f1sh but I don't know how to check this case, the problem is essentially only this

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="http://SomeServerName";
          String s1=s.substring(s.indexOf("://")+3);
          if(s1.indexOf("/")==-1) {
              System.out.println(s1);
          }else {
              System.out.println(s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf("/")));
          }
```

Comment: code-only solutions are discouraged. please read [answer]. explain what you changed, explain what fixes OPs problem and why it does so. give details, elaborate. SO is a place for **high quality** questions **and** answers.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant for OP, but note that this doesnt work with complex URLs that use `/` in the credentials part, for example. E.g. the complex but valid URL: `https://https:⁄⁄www.netmeister.org@https://www.netmeister.org/https:⁄⁄www.netmeister.org⁄?https://www.netmeister.org=https://www.netmeister.org;https://www.netmeister.org#https://www.netmeister.org`. See https://www.netmeister.org/blog/urls.html

Answer (score -1):

```
        // Sample String s.
        String s = "http://SomeServerName/abcd/dfdf.htm?dfdf=dfdf";
        /*
           get a substring(startIndex, endIndex)
           startIndex : search for index of string "//" and add its length to get to end of it.
           endIndex: input string length.
         */
        String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("//")+2,s.length());
        /*
           get a substring(startIndex, endIndex)
           startIndex : 0
           endIndex : starting index of "/" if present or length of string s1
        */
        String output = s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf("/") > 0 ? s1.indexOf("/") : s1.length());
        System.out.println(output);     // output : SomeServerName
```

Comment: Also the usage of `split` is not allowed according to the question.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant for OP, but note that this doesnt work with complex URLs that use `/` in the credentials part, for example. E.g. the complex but valid URL: `https://https:⁄⁄www.netmeister.org@https://www.netmeister.org/https:⁄⁄www.netmeister.org⁄?https://www.netmeister.org=https://www.netmeister.org;https://www.netmeister.org#https://www.netmeister.org`. See https://www.netmeister.org/blog/urls.html